# Can emacs auto-save backtrace?

Tags: spacemacs, debugging, backtrace

Trying to debug a problem with `debug-on-error`. Backtrace appears for a second and then some other parts of the system make it disappear and emacs becomes dysfunctional so I can never read it.

Is there a way to get emacs to write the backtrace to a file when its generated?

Comment: If you type `M-x list-buffers` is your backtrace buffer still there and you can just switch to it?  Unless you exited recursive-edit or killed the backtrace buffer, the backtrace buffer may still be present.

Comment: You may wish to try advising the *function* `debug` so that the your save buffer function gets triggered after the buffer is populated.

Answer (score 2):

Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not then recursively bisect your init file to find out what is causing the problem (e.g. `*Backtrace*` seeming to disappear and Emacs becoming dysfunctional).

If you still see the problem with `emacs -Q` then consider reporting an Emacs bug.

If buffer `*Backtrace*` has not been killed then you can visit it again (`C-x b`) and then write it to a file using `C-x C-w`.  (Since it is not visiting a file there is no autosaving or backup file produced for the buffer.)

[Your question is anyway unclear in some respects. Specify what exactly you mean by "emacs becomes dysfunctional", for example.]

Comment: Its a bug with spacemacs https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/8485 which is like, the mother of all init files; impossible to bisect. I mean, I do know what neighborhood the error lives in, it has to do with a bad interaction between the mu4e mail layer and helm. They ask for a backtrace but I simply can't capture it because helm replaces features like C-x b and C-x C-w and helm is whats crashed.

Comment: Glad you're making progress debugging it. If it is a spacemacs bug why can't you repro it without involving helm? Try to keep your repro recipe as simple as possible.